# Jsoup, navigate tag tree with prefixed path

Tags: android, dom, jsoup

I already know the path of some element inside an html page, and i want extract some data. There's a function to perform this navigation by insert full path?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in addition to the direct DOM-navigation methods (getChildren(), etc.) there is also much more powerful way - the Selector. It is a mechanism for CSS-like filtering of elements that match a query string. You can apply query to a given node as well to the whole document.

For example:

```
Document doc;
String query = "body table.mainouter tr:eq(1) img[src$=.png]";
Elements tags = doc.select(query);
if (!tags.isEmpty())
{
  Element tagImg = tags.first();
  String srcImg = tagImg.attr("src");
}
```

This means *"Give me the first PNG IMG element in the first TR inside of TABLE of class mainouter"*. Note that query is not a unique address but if you narrow it and add enough criteria to the query it practically becomes unique path. This way it will return collection of only 1 element. The nice thing is that you don't need to add all elements of the path, only those that are disambiguating the results (reducing the results to exactly what you search for).